# managing the sidebar in beamer LaTeX (Goettingen)

Tags: beamer, navigation

I'm going to use beamer-LaTeX give a very long presentation (~10 hours), actually a thorough synopsis of a uni course.

I need structure, so I'd like to use sections and subsections, but if I let appear them all, the right column will be quite full (I like to use the `Goettingen`, but `Bergen` or `Hannover` would be fine as well). Is there a way I can force the subsections of section 1, 3, 4 etc. disappear from the right column when I'm currently discussing section 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily the `Goettingen` theme has a build-in option to hide subsections of other sections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Goettingen}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
\subsection{sub1}
\frame{abc}

\section{sec2}
\subsection{sub2}
\frame{abc} 

\end{document}
```

[image]